# I created a VM and installed Linux on it, but it shows a blank terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox with Windows 10 Home (64-bit). Then I created a VM and tried to choose Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Desktop as the start-up disk, but it just shows a dark purple background with a blinking white underscore in the top left corner. Why is it doing this and how can I get past it?

Comment: We need more information than this. How did you install Ubuntu? Where and when do you get the blank terminal? Is it blank or a color? How long do you wait til you give up? What are you running VirtualBox on? Please edit your question with the answers.

Comment: After you created the VM, did you install Linux?  Creating the VM doesn't install the OS. You need to download, mount, boot from and install Ubuntu from the ISO file.

Comment: @essjae Well I did choose the startup disk file. How do you download, mount, boot, and install? Sorry I'm kind of new to VMs. 

Comment: Do you have a large ISO file that you downloaded from Ubunut?  This should get you started: https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-Linux-on-your-Windows/

Comment: @essjae I did it and it showed me the Linux Mint logo while counting down to automatically booting. When I pressed any key it would show a list of options. I'm not sure what they do and which one I should pick. Also, do I have to verify my ISO?

Comment: If you can boot and install from the ISO, there's no need to verify it.